# Derivation of Rayleigh-distributed random variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable, uniform-distribution, rayleigh-distribution

I only have a uniform distribution function between [0,1]. And from this distribution, I should generate a sequence of Rayleigh distributed random variable using some software.

Anyhow, I was able to finish the problem using the formula from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) article:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;X=\sigma\sqrt{-2\ln(U)}$$

However, there is only one thing I could not understand. I tried many times to derive formula $(1)$ using the [Inverse transform sampling method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling_method), but  I could not.

Can someone show me the steps of how $(1)$ is found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If random variable $X$ has CDF $F(x)$, then $F^{-1}(U)$ is a sample of $X$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval. This is a standard result in probability
theory, and I assume that you do not need a proof of this.

The CDF of a Rayleigh random variable $X$ is
$$F(x) = 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right), ~~x \geq 0,$$ and so $F^{-1}(y) = \sigma\sqrt{-2\ln(1-y)}$. But, since $1-U$ is *also* uniformly distributed on the unit interval, we save
one subtraction by using $X = \sigma\sqrt{-2\ln( U})$ instead.

Comment: (+1) Important aside: Make sure you know how your random number generator works before saving the subtraction. Some RNGs will have zero as a valid output while others won't. The consequences could be severe. Likewise some RNGs may admit one as a valid output.

Comment: @cardinal Nice point! And if the RNG has both $0$ and $1$ as possible valid outputs, then some re-programming might be necessary...